# Incomplete translation in Terraria

Tags: terraria

I'm trying to play Terraria in French, but for some reason not all the text seems to be translated. For example, some items have their French names, while others have their English names.

The weird thing is that it's inconsistent. When I'm playing multiplayer with a friend, the part of the game which is translated seems to change (other objects have their name translated compared to my single player game for example).

Any idea on how I can fix this and get a consistent translation?

Comment: you can install a mod for fanmade translations

Comment: Any hints for where to look? I already tried searching before asking the question and I couldn't find any.